# unsupported value error. trying to insert user data into database, while first selecting the key in one table

Tags: flask, cs50

I'm working on my final project for CS50. The idea is to create something like the IMDB but for specialty coffee. I've managed to create a sql database and get the flask app running and let the user add information about a coffee to my database.

The problem is the following: I wand there to be a rating feature where the user can rate a particular coffee. That rating should be send to the ratings table in my database. I tried to have a relational database, where the coffee_id is the FOREIGN KEY in the coffee_ratings table.

Now that's where I'm still doing something wrong. From the terminal window I see that all the SELECT queries seem to work but somehow I still get "unsupported value {id:1} - one being the selected coffee_id from the coffees table here....

traceback (most recent call last):

```
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
            db.execute("INSERT INTO coffee_ratings (coffee_id, rating) VALUES (?, ?)", coffee_id, rating)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'll inclue my python code here:
(I commeted out additional ratings aroma, body ...that I ultimately would like to include as well, so I can fix the rating first)

```
`@app.route("/score", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def score():
        if request.method =="POST":`

            name = request.form.get("name")
            rating = request.form.get("rating")
            #aroma = request.form.get("aroma")
           # body = request.form.get("body")

            coffee_id = db.execute("SELECT id FROM coffees WHERE name LIKE ?", name)
              # Check if the coffee exists in the database
            if coffee_id is not None:
                coffee_id = coffee_id[0]  # Extracting the ID from the dictionary
            #aroma_id = db.execute("SELECT id FROM aromas WHERE aroma_name = ?", aroma)
           # body_id = db.execute("SELECT id FROM bodies WHERE body_name = ?", body)
           # db.execute("INSERT INTO coffee_ratings (coffee_id, aroma_id, body_id, rating) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", coffee_id, aroma_id, body_id, rating)
                db.execute("INSERT INTO coffee_ratings (coffee_id, rating) VALUES (?, ?)", coffee_id, rating)
                return render_template("score.html")
            else:
                return f"Coffee '{name}' not found in the database."

        else:
            row = db.execute("SELECT * FROM coffee_ratings;")
            return render_template("score.html", score = row)`
```

here is my score.html:

```
`<form action="/score" method="post">
    <input id="name" autocomplete="off" autofocus name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
    <input id="rating" autocomplete="off" autofocus name="rating" placeholder="rating" type="number" min="1" max="10">
    <button type="submit">score</button>
</form>`
```

Here the .schema (only coffees and ratings table)

CREATE TABLE coffee_ratings (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
coffee_id INTEGER,
aroma_id INTEGER,
taste_id INTEGER,
body_id INTEGER,
bitterness_id INTEGER,
sourness_id INTEGER,
rating INTEGER NOT NULL,
votes INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (coffee_id) REFERENCES coffees(id),
FOREIGN KEY (aroma_id) REFERENCES aromas(id),
FOREIGN KEY (taste_id) REFERENCES tastes(id),
FOREIGN KEY (body_id) REFERENCES bodies(id),
FOREIGN KEY (bitterness_id) REFERENCES bitterness(id)
);

CREATE TABLE coffees (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
name TEXT NOT NULL,
roaster TEXT,
country TEXT,
variety TEXT,
farm TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE aromas (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
aroma_name TEXT NOT NULL
);
Thank's in advance for your help.

Cheers
Nico

Comment: Please include the full traceback of your error in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cs50 `execute` returns a list of dictionaries. This `coffee_id = coffee_id[0]` is the first *row* returned by `execute`, which is `{'id': 1}` as per the error message. Insert query needs the value of the key `id` from the first row.